# Why aren't "minimum requirements not met" asterisks on Area 51 shown to logged-out users?

Tags: support, bug, area-51, anonymous

Today, I noticed that there were a large amount of proposals which did not meet the 3-day minimum requirements. Ordinarily, there is an asterisk shown next to each one that does not meet them:

[image: Asterisks on proposals that don't meet the requirements, shown to logged-in users]

However, this asterisk is only shown to registered users logged in to their accounts. Logged-out users don't see those asterisks:

[image: ...but not to logged-out users]

Why are these asterisks hidden from logged-out users? If they're supposed to be hidden, why is the notice regarding asterisks still shown to them?